# php search and get parent array elements

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have assoc php array

```
0 => array
    (
        'categoryName' => 'Moto'
        'categoryTitle' => 'Moto'
        'categorySlug' => 'moto-and-tech'
        'categoryAttr' => array
        (
            0 => 'test1'
            1 => 'test2'
            2 => 'test3'
            3 => 'test4'
        )
        'categoryNested' => array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'categoryName' => 'anything'
                'categoryTitle' => 'anything'
                'categorySlug' => 'anything'
                'categoryAttr' => array
                (
                    0 => 'test1'
                    1 => 'test1'
                    2 => 'test1'
                    3 => 'test1'
                )
                'categoryNested' => array()
            )
            1 => array
            (
                'categoryName' => 'any'
                'categoryTitle' => 'any'
                'categorySlug' => 'any'
                'categoryAttr' => array
                (
                    0 => 'test1'
                    1 => 'test1'
                    2 => 'test1'
                    3 => 'test1'
                )
                'categoryNested' => array()
            )
```

How i can search inserted array by `key(catgorySlug)`, and return all parent elements categoryName ?

Comment: You need use recursion.

Comment: You should specify how you want the result value to be formatted...

Answer (score 1):

For unknown array depth use recursion

```
function array_searchRecursive( $needle, $haystack, $strict=false, $path=array() )
{

    foreach( $haystack as $key => $val ) {
        if( is_array($val) && $subPath = array_searchRecursive($needle, $val, $strict, $path) ) {
            $path = array_merge($path, array($key), $subPath);
            return $path;
        } elseif( (!$strict && $val == $needle) || ($strict && $val === $needle) ) {
            $path[] = $key;
            return $path;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Parameters:**
mixed needle - what you search
array haystack - search object
bool strict - accept "1" for 1 ?
array path - used for recursion, ignore.

**return**

You will get either the array path, or false. Call with

```
array_searchRecursive($myhaystackarray, 'myneedle');
```

Comment: I don't know count nested array, it must be recursive

Comment: @John edited accordingly.

Comment: @John Please don´t forget to upvote and accept answers that helped you, to help people with similar problems visiting that site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is such recursive function, hope this helps:

```
$array = array
(
    'categoryName' => 'Moto',
    'categoryTitle' => 'Moto',
    'categorySlug' => 'moto-and-tech',
    'categoryAttr' => array
    (
        0 => 'test1',
        1 => 'test2',
        2 => 'test3',
        3 => 'test4'
    ),
    'categoryNested' => array
    (
        0 => array
        (
            'categoryName' => 'anything',
            'categoryTitle' => 'anything',
            'categorySlug' => 'anything',
            'categoryAttr' => array
            (
                0 => 'test1',
                1 => 'test1',
                2 => 'test1',
                3 => 'test1'
            ),
            'categoryNested' => array()
        ),
        1 => array
        (
            'categoryName' => 'any',
            'categoryTitle' => 'any',
            'categorySlug' => 'any',
            'categoryAttr' => array
            (
                0 => 'test1',
                1 => 'test1',
                2 => 'test1',
                3 => 'test1'
            ),
            'categoryNested' => array()
        )
    )
);

function findByKey($key,$tmp) {
    $results = array();
    foreach($tmp as $k=>$v) {
        if ($k===$key && !is_array($v)) {
           $results[]=$v;
        }
        if (is_array($v)) {
           $results = array_merge($results,findByKey($key,$v));
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

$results = findByKey('categoryTitle',$array);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: I think you've only need to look in categoryNested and for a value in categorySlug

Comment: I would really advise against the usage of 'global'. Imagine you were searching a password array from withhin a private class. All the paswords would become globally public.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy added a fix :)